# What would we the cleanest way to access data attribute INSIDE the datatables initialisation method

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Does anyone know by any chance how come neither of those two initialisation excerpts work? Although the table has `data` HTML attribute javascript still can't extract that value

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
            ajax: $(this).data("ajaxurl"),
            columns: [
                { data: "id" },
                { data: "ip_address" },
                { data: "reason" }
            ]
        });


$('.datatable').dataTable({
            ajax: this.dataset.ajaxurl,
            columns: [
                { data: "id" },
                { data: "ip_address" },
                { data: "reason" }
            ]
        });
```

Seems like dataTable() function has a different scope from the one I expected so `this` does not hold the reference to the DOM element.

What would we the cleanest way to access data attribute INSIDE the initialisation method? I was able to do this

```
var oTable = $('.datatable');
oTable.dataTable({
            ajax: oTable.data("ajaxurl"),
            columns: [
                { data: "id" },
                { data: "ip_address" },
                { data: "reason" }
            ]
        });
```

but I want the initialisation code to be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `this` variable out of context, that is why it's not an instance of DataTables object and both of your examples didn't work.

Your last example is proper way to access jQuery object during initialization.

However DataTables already support `data-` attributes for initialization, see [this demo](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html). For example, you can use `data-ajax` to define `ajax` property value:

```
<table class="datatable display" data-ajax="/post/ajax.php">
</table>
```

Your code then could be simplified to:

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    columns: [
        { data: "id" },
        { data: "ip_address" },
        { data: "reason" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Great, datatables seems to have evolved since the last time I used it ages ago. It's a very handy feature

Answer (score -1):

This is an `table` DOM element.

For example:

```
<table class="datatable" data-ajaxurl="/post/ajax.php">
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does not seem this way though as I can't access the element data using `this.dataset.ajaxurl`

Comment: `var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("datatable")[0]; console.log(obj.dataset.ajaxurl);` works though. Isn't `this` from the code in the question supposed to be the same as `obj` i retrieve with native JS?

Comment: this - ref, $(this) - obj